# Android: How to clear all items in a custom listview

Tags: android, listview

I know the normal listview can be cleared by calling 'clear' to arrayadapter etc. But how we do clear items if it is a custom listview ??

Here is my code :

Activity:

```
public class GroupList extends Activity{
    TextView v_no_groups;
    Cursor grouplist_cur;
    Context context = GroupList.this;
    SQLiteDatabase mydb=null;
    ListView v_grouplist;
    ArrayList<String> grpname_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<String> grpid_arr = new ArrayList<String>();
    ArrayList<Integer> memcount_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    ArrayList<Integer> totaltrans_arr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    M_grplist_adapter mga;
    Button v_creategrp;
    List<M_grplist_class> glist;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.grouplist);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {

        super.onResume();

        //mga.clearlistview();

        v_creategrp = (Button)findViewById(R.id.x_creategrp);
        v_grouplist = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        registerForContextMenu(v_grouplist);
        v_no_groups = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.x_no_groups);

        mydb = this.openOrCreateDatabase("moneydb", 0, null);
        mydb.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS grouptable(grpname varchar(30),grpid varchar(10),memcount number(3),totaltrans number(3))");   
        grouplist_cur = mydb.rawQuery("SELECT * from grouptable", null);

        if(grouplist_cur.getCount()>0)
        {

            grouplist_cur.moveToFirst();
            do{
                grpname_arr.add(grouplist_cur.getString(0));
                memcount_arr.add(grouplist_cur.getInt(2));
                totaltrans_arr.add(grouplist_cur.getInt(3));
            }while(grouplist_cur.moveToNext());

            glist = new ArrayList<M_grplist_class>();
            for(int i=grpname_arr.size()-1;i>=0;i--){
                glist.add(new M_grplist_class(grpname_arr.get(i),memcount_arr.get(i),totaltrans_arr.get(i)));
            }

            mga = new M_grplist_adapter(context,glist);
            v_grouplist.setAdapter(mga);

            grouplist_cur.close();
            mydb.close();
        }
        else
        {
            grouplist_cur.close();
            mydb.close();
        }

        v_creategrp.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
            public void onClick(View v){
                Intent int_newgrp = new Intent(context,NewGroup.class);
                startActivity(int_newgrp);
            }
        });
    }
```

grplist_adapter class:

```
public class M_grplist_adapter extends BaseAdapter{
    private List<M_grplist_class> items = null;
    private Context context;
    private int index;

    public M_grplist_adapter(Context context,List<M_grplist_class> items){
        items.clear();
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        this.items = items;
        this.context = context;
        //notifyDataSetChanged();
        Log.i("Dillu", "you are here M_grplist_adapter");
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        Log.i("Dillu", "you are here getcount");
        return items.size();

    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        index = position;
        Log.i("Dillu", "you are here getitem");
        return items.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        Log.i("Dillu", "you are here getitemid");
        return position;
    }

    public String clear()
    {
        String name = items.get(index).getgrpname();
        items.remove(index);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int index, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Log.i("Dillu", "you are here getview");
        LinearLayout rowLayout=null;
        if(convertView==null) 
            rowLayout = (LinearLayout)LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.m_grplist_item,parent,false);
        else
            rowLayout = (LinearLayout)convertView;  

        TextView gname = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.grpname);
        gname.setText(items.get(index).getgrpname());

        TextView gmems = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.noofmems);
        int int_temp = items.get(index).getmemcount();
        String str_temp = Integer.toString(int_temp);
        gmems.setText(str_temp);

        TextView gtrans = (TextView)rowLayout.findViewById(R.id.nooftrans);
        int int_temp_1 = items.get(index).gettotaltrans();
        String str_temp_1 = Integer.toString(int_temp_1);
        gtrans.setText(str_temp_1);

        return rowLayout;
    }

}
```

M_grplist_class :

```
public class M_grplist_class {
    String loc_grpname;
    int loc_memcount;
    int loc_totaltrans;

     public M_grplist_class(String grpname,int memcount,int totaltrans){
         loc_grpname = grpname;
         loc_memcount = memcount;
         loc_totaltrans = totaltrans; 
     }

     public String getgrpname(){
         return loc_grpname;
     }

     public int getmemcount(){
         return loc_memcount;
     }

     public int gettotaltrans(){
         return loc_totaltrans;
     }

}
```

Please provide a solution for this.

Comment: No, my problem didnt get solved.

Answer (score 7):

You need to call [notifyDataSetChanged()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/BaseAdapter.html#notifyDataSetChanged%28%29) on your adapter after clearing your underlying list. Your `ListView` will register itself a an observer and react to that call.

```
public void clearlistview()
{
    items.clear();
    this.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I had added the notifyDataSetChanged() in clearlistview(). But logcat displaying an error at mga.clearlistview();. Is my code correct?? I tried calling notifyDataSetChanged() in constructor. But my activity is displaying an empty listview. Can you please provide any sample code if possible ??

Comment: Is there really a need to make a new `ArrayList`, add an item, then clear all items? Also, you need to make sure you call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after calling `setAdapter()` on your `ListView`.

Comment: Yeah, I have to call a new Activity from the current activity. There will be database operations in the new Activity. And after finishing operations i should come back to the old activity and the listview in the old activity should be updated with the database operations made.So I wrote the code of old activity in onResume() so that the listview will be updated(calling notifyDataSetChanged() doesnt update database operations in listview). But the data in listview is  getting duplicated. So i have to clear all items and  add updated items.

Comment: Can you provide me a sample code for activity. I dont know whether the placement of mga.clearlistview(); in my code is correct or not.

Comment: See my first comment, that should explain things. You're calling `clearlistview()` in the wrong order.

Answer (score 3):

Simply use listView.setAdapter(null);

This work for me.

Answer (score 0):

In your code you must clear "glist" i.e., glist.clear but you shuld not call mga.clearlistview();

glist is the original arraylist of items where as "item" is only a copy of glist.

Refer this Links for more details about custom adapters.

[LINK1](http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/13/custom-baseadapters/)

Comment: I removed the mga.clearlistview(); and added glist.clear();. But this doesnt making any difference. The data is duplicating when I come back to activity.The problem is, in grplist_adapter class, I dont know where to add items.clear(); and notifyDataSetChanged(); to clear the items in adapter.

Comment: sorry, i didnt get any info required for me from that link.

Answer (score 0):

as per my knowledge there is  no need to clear adapter and set notifyDataSetChanged() to the adapter.
u have used List,ArrayList For the item or the Array 1 st clear it and reinitialize it and After passing the data to costume adapter clear the used array/list.It will working fine!